# How to find function existence border

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I have a function like this

```
f[x_, a_] = Log[-x - a]*(-x - a) + Sin[a];
```

this function does exist if x > a because of Log[]. a - parameters.
if I plot a few graphs with different a like this

```
Plot[{f[x, 1], f[x, 1.4], f[x, 1.8], f[x, 2]}, {x, -4, 4}]
```

I get a graph like this

[image]

My Question:
Can I get somehow a function of the last existing point of the f[], like FLast[x] like I marked in the graph by black dots?
Of course I understand that function f[] exists everywhere, but becomes complex at point x=a and if I will plot Re[f[...]] it will plot graph everywhere.

In other words I need to find a border, where my function becomes complex.

This is an artificial example and most probably it is possible to find analitycal solution for this function f[], but my real function is numeric solution of differential equation which is very complicated and cannot be found analitically.

Comment: For your simple example, you can use `FunctionDomain[]`. For your *actual problem* (based on your sketch), you can probably use `WhenEvent[]`.

Comment: Will FunctionDomain work for complicated numerical function?

Comment: Likely, no. Since you didn't post your DE, I only gave a hint on using event detection for your purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way that goes into the innards of the `Plot`, extracts the lines, finds the last points, and adds them to the plot:

```
f[x_, a_] = Log[-x - a]*(-x - a) + Sin[a];
Show[
  #,
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Black, Point@*Last /@ Cases[Normal@#, Line[a_] :> Sort[a], Infinity]}
 ] &@ Plot[{f[x, 1], f[x, 1.4], f[x, 1.8], f[x, 2]}, {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I do not need a points. I need a function like FLast[x] to perform further analysis. Finally I do not need the grapf of f[x,a], I really only need FLast[x]. As I understand I could find it by solving equation Im[f[x,a]]==0+, but even NSolve[Im[f[x,1]]==0.001, x] does not work.

Comment: NSolve[f[x,1]==0.001*I, x] works fine, but looks like mathematica works strange with Im[] function.

Comment: @Zlelik. I recommend taking J.M.'s advice and posting more details about your code. J.M. is right that probably `WhenEvent` inside `NDSolve` is the way to go, but there's no way to help without seeing your code to begin with. Nonetheless, I might try to take J.M.'s suggestion about `FunctionDomain' and post something about it if I find the time.

Comment: It is really difficult to post code, because it is really huge, I think 10 pages of code and execution time 2 days. I will try to make simplified example with NDSolve.

But in General why NSolve[Im[f[x,1]]==0.001, x] does not work?